# Can we derive results from infinite sequences of integration by parts?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, soft-question

I remember from my school days some old trick with integrals where if $\sin$ or $\cos$ were involved, we could sometimes apply the partial integration theorem once or twice and express the first integral in terms of itself in a way which let us solve it. An example:

$$I=\int\sin(x)^2dx = x -\int \cos(x)^2dx = x - \sin(x)\cos(x) - \int \sin(x)^2dx$$

Now rearranging gives $$2I = x-\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Which we can verify.

Now to the question, can this be applied in a more general setting?

For example if we do not after a finite set of steps end up with a closed form expression, could we use a series of integrals which might arise from iterating the integration-by-parts indefinitely? Are there any particular problems solvable this way which aren't solvable otherwise?

Comment: "For example if we do not after a finite set of steps end up with a closed form expression, could we use a series of integrals which might arise from iterating the integration-by-parts indefinitely? "

If $f$ is a smooth function and $g$ is integrable then the integration by parts formula can be recursively applied for $\int fg$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good example is the erfc function expanded around $x = \infty$:
\begin{align} \text{erfc}(x) &:= \frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty e^{-y^2} \, dy
\\ &= \frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty \frac 1y y e^{-y^2} \, dy
\\ &= \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac 1{2x} e^{-x^2} - \frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty \frac 1{2y^2} e^{-y^2} \, dy
\\ &= \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac 1{2x} e^{-x^2} - \frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty \frac 1{2y^3} y e^{-y^2} \, dy
\\ &= \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac 1{2x} e^{-x^2} - \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac 1{4x^3} e^{-x^2} + \frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty \frac 3{4y^4} e^{-y^2} \, dy
\\ & = \cdots
\end{align}
Note that the last term gives you a good estimate of the remainder.  For example
$$ \frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_x^\infty \frac 3{4y^4} e^{-y^2} \, dy \le \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac 3{4x^4} \int_x^\infty e^{-y^2} \, dy < \frac1{\sqrt \pi} \frac 3{8x^5} e^{-x^2} .$$
(I may have got some details wrong, but I think you can see the idea.)

Comment: Yes, good answer, this is the same principle as the one used in estimating oscillatory integrals. The lemma of van der Corput is proven exactly like this (cfr. Eli Stein’s “Harmonic Analysis”, in the chapter on oscillatory integrals of the first kind).

Answer (score 1):

A nice example is going the "wrong way" on an easy integral to get the Maclaurin series of $e^x$.
$$
1-e^{-x}=\int_0^x e^{-t}\,dt;
$$
$$
1-e^{-x}=\int_0^x \underbrace{e^{-t}}_{u}\cdot \underbrace{1dt}_{dv} = x e^{-x} + \int_0^x t e^{-t}\,dt
$$
$$
= x e^{-x} +\frac{x^2}{2}e^{-x} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^x t^2 e^{-t}{dt}
$$
$$
= x e^{-x} +\frac{x^2}{2}e^{-x} + \frac{x^3}{6}e^{-x}+ \frac{1}{6}\int_0^x t^2 e^{-t}{dt}
$$Then denoting $\displaystyle{I_n = \frac{1}{n!}\int_0^x t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt}$, we have
$$
1=e^{-x}\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}\right) +I_n
$$Then for fixed $x$ we have
$$
\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n\right|\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x^n|}{n!}=0,
$$yielding
$$
1 = e^{-x}\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots\right);\qquad e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$

Comment: A great example of how doing something seemingly unnecessarily complicated but which paves the way for a whole new technique of solving a lot harder problems.